# `dplyr::between` over millions of intervals: how to make it faster

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, for-loop, between

I have a data frame with *startValue* (in column `X1`) and *endValue* (in column `X2`), and a list of outliers. I need to count how many outliers fall within those specific *startValue* and *endValue*. Here is a minimal example and my attempt:

```
library("dplyr")

set.seed(2022)

dat = data.frame(matrix(sort(sample(1:500, 50)), ncol = 2, byrow = T))
dim(dat)
dat$Outliers = NA

outliers = sort(sample(1:500, 30))

for (i in 1:25){
  dat$Outliers[i] = length(which(between(outliers, dat$X1[i], dat$X2[i]) == T))
}
```

This code works fine. But my real data have **millions of row** and this `for` loop takes a lot of time. Is there a faster way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**a shallow fix at coding level**

You will see an immediate speedup, with the following modification:

```
out <- integer(nrow(dat))
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  out[i] <- sum(between(outliers, dat$X1[i], dat$X2[i]))
}
dat$Outliers1 <- out
with(dat, identical(Outliers, Outliers1))  ## the result is correct
#[1] TRUE
```

1. This avoids modifying a data.frame during a loop, hence a lot of unnecessary memory copies (which is particularly important if you have a big data.frame).
2. `length(which(LogicalVec == TRUE))` is awkward; use `sum(LogicalVec)`.

You can also try replacing this loop using:

```
dat$Outliers2 <- mapply(\(a, b) sum(between(outliers, a, b)), dat$X1, dat$X2)
with(dat, identical(Outliers, Outliers2))  ## the result is correct
#[1] TRUE
```

[Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712) mentioned a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
d_vals <- as.data.table(outliers)
dat[ , Outliers3 := d_vals[dat, on = .(outliers >= X1, outliers <= X2), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
with(dat, identical(Outliers, Outliers3))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

**a deep fix at algorithm level**

If your real data are like what you have simulated, with non-overlapping intervals `[startValue, endValue]`, you can use `base::findInterval` rather than `dplyr::between`. The only problem, is that `findInterval` uses interval **[a, b)** while `between` uses **[a, b]**. So if an outlier value happens to equal an *endValue*, `between` will count it twice, whereas `findInterval` only count it once. This does occur for you minimal example.

```
vec <- c(with(dat, rbind(X1, X2)))
if (is.unsorted(vec, strictly = TRUE)) stop("cannot apply this method!")
x <- findInterval(outliers, vec, rightmost.closed = TRUE)
x <- x[x %% 2 == 1]  ## get rid of X2[i] ~ X1[i + 1]; just keep X1[i] ~ X2[i]
x <- (x + 1) / 2
dat$Outliers4 <- tabulate(x, nrow(dat))
with(dat, identical(Outliers, Outliers4))  ## oops, the results are not identical
#[1] FALSE

## you see, the first interval is causing problem
with(dat, Outliers - Outliers4)
#[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

## inspect the first interval
dat[1, 1:2]
#  X1 X2
#1  1  3

## inspect outliers: 3 is an outlier value
## it is not in [1, 3), so not counted by `findInterval`
## but it is in [1, 3], so counted by `between`
outliers
# [1]   1   3  19  32  42  56  87  99 120 218 234 248 276 287 306 316 319 336 351
#[20] 353 361 382 389 400 417 423 425 458 467 480
```

Well, depending on what you want in the end, you may or may not fix this discrepancy. If you do want to fix, you could do:

```
i <- which(dat$X2 %in% outliers)
dat$Outliers4[i] <- dat$Outliers4[i] + 1L
with(dat, identical(Outliers, Outliers4))
#[1] TRUE
```

Hang on, this assumes that your `outliers` have no duplicated values. If some value appears more than once, you need to plus the number of duplicates instead of 1. You need:

```
i <- which(dat$X2 %in% outliers)
m <- colSums(matrix(outliers %in% dat$X2[i], ncol = length(i)))
dat$Outliers4[i] <- dat$Outliers4[i] + m
```

---

**benchmark**

```
## a 1000 x 2 data.frame
set.seed(2022)
dat = data.frame(matrix(sort(sample(20000, 2000)), ncol = 2, byrow = T))
outliers = sort(sample(20000, 1000))
```

```
## your current method
method0 <- function (dat, outliers) {
  dat$Outliers = NA
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    dat$Outliers[i] = length(which(between(outliers, dat$X1[i], dat$X2[i]) == T))
  }
  dat
}
```

```
## modified `for`-loop method
method1 <- function (dat, outliers) {
  out <- integer(nrow(dat))
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    out[i] <- sum(between(outliers, dat$X1[i], dat$X2[i]))
  }
  dat$Outliers <- out
  dat
}

## `mapply` method
method2 <- function (dat, outliers) {
  dat$Outliers <- mapply(\(a, b) sum(between(outliers, a, b)), dat$X1, dat$X2)
  dat
}
```

```
## "data.table" method
method3 <- function (dat, outliers) {
  DT <- as.data.table(dat)
  d_vals <- as.data.table(outliers)
  DT[ , Outliers := d_vals[DT, on = .(outliers >= X1, outliers <= X2), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
  DT
}
```

```
## fineInterval() + tabulate(), with optional discrepancy fix
method4 <- function (dat, outliers, fix = FALSE) {
  vec <- c(with(dat, rbind(X1, X2)))
  if (is.unsorted(vec, strictly = TRUE)) stop("cannot apply this method!")
  x <- findInterval(outliers, vec, rightmost.closed = TRUE)
  x <- x[x %% 2 == 1]
  x <- (x + 1) / 2
  out <- tabulate(x, nrow(dat))
  if (fix) {
    i <- which(dat$X2 %in% outliers)
    if (anyDuplicated(outliers)) {
      m <- colSums(matrix(outliers %in% dat$X2[i], ncol = length(i)))
    } else {
      m <- 1L
    }
    out[i] <- out[i] + m
  }
  dat$Outliers <- out
  dat
}
```

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(method0 = method0(dat, outliers),
               method1 = method1(dat, outliers),
               method2 = method2(dat, outliers),
               method3 = method3(dat, outliers),
               method4F = method4(dat, outliers, fix = FALSE),
               method4T = method4(dat, outliers, fix = TRUE))
#Unit: microseconds
#     expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#  method0 40459.251 40854.4165 44121.8656 41015.071 46436.530 171540.17   100
#  method1 20755.578 20905.8405 21740.9797 21032.032 21309.445  30860.18   100
#  method2 19320.867 19483.9885 20452.9461 19585.355 19808.503  26417.01   100
#  method3  4920.958  5171.5260  5411.6465  5340.284  5379.681  12849.05   100
# method4F   160.382   180.7245   260.6430   217.843   228.279   5548.48   100
# method4T   331.903   353.5260   612.7073   388.385   410.383  23536.62   100
```

So [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is the fastest solution at coding level, about 7 ~ 8 times faster. But if intervals do not overlap, then an improved algorithm gives 100+ times speedup! The discrepancy fix is not free, but is still fast.

---

**hint**

If you do have overlapping intervals, the `findInterval` + `tabulate` method can still be applied. The key is to work with non-overlapping intervals first, then aggregate the counts. Here is a conceptual illustration. Suppose we have two overlapping intervals:

```
[1, 3], [2, 5]
```

We can first separate them to non-overlapping ones:

```
[1, 2), [2, 3), [3, 5]
```

Now, `findInterval` + `tabulate` can find counts on these intervals:

| [1, 2) | [2, 3) | [3, 5] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | N2 | N3 |

The desired result is an aggregation:

| [1, 3) | [2, 5] |
| --- | --- |
| N1 + N2 | N2 + N3 |

Remember: Nothing is faster than using a clever algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are all integer, here's an option that uses just `cumsum(tabulate(`.

```
f2 <- function(dat, outliers) {
  # proposed function
  x <- cumsum(tabulate(outliers, max(dat$X2)))
  if(dat$X1[1] <= 1L) {
    x[dat$X2] - c(0L, x[dat$X1 - 1L])
  } else {
    x[dat$X2] - x[dat$X1 - 1L]
  }
}
```

Benchmarking

```
library("dplyr")

set.seed(2022)
dat = data.frame(matrix(sort(sample(20000, 2000)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
outliers = sort(sample(20000, 1000))

f1 <- function(dat, outliers) {
  # modified original function
  out <- integer(nrow(dat))
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) out[i] <- sum(between(outliers, dat$X1[i], dat$X2[i]))
  out
}

f2 <- function(dat, outliers) {
  # proposed function
  x <- cumsum(tabulate(outliers, max(dat$X2)))
  if(dat$X1[1] <= 1L) {
    x[dat$X2] - c(0L, x[dat$X1 - 1L])
  } else {
    x[dat$X2] - x[dat$X1 - 1L]
  }
}

f3 <- function (dat, outliers, fix = FALSE) {
  # Zheyuan Li's function
  vec <- c(with(dat, rbind(X1, X2)))
  if (is.unsorted(vec, strictly = TRUE)) stop("cannot apply this method!")
  x <- findInterval(outliers, vec, rightmost.closed = TRUE)
  x <- x[x %% 2 == 1]
  x <- (x + 1) / 2
  out <- tabulate(x, nrow(dat))
  if (fix) {
    i <- which(dat$X2 %in% outliers)
    if (anyDuplicated(outliers)) {
      m <- colSums(matrix(outliers %in% dat$X2[i], ncol = length(i)))
    } else {
      m <- 1L
    }
    out[i] <- out[i] + m
  }
  out
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(dat, outliers),
                               f2 = f2(dat, outliers),
                               f3 = f3(dat, outliers, TRUE),
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>    f1 6032.8 6175.65 6934.492 6273.80 7079.35 12692.0   100
#>    f2   42.6   44.55  110.630   46.65   51.45  3925.9   100
#>    f3   71.4   82.20  106.223  100.25  128.25   194.0   100

# increase the number of evaluations
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f2 = f2(dat, outliers),
                               f3 = f3(dat, outliers, TRUE),
                               times = 1e3L,
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr  min   lq    mean median   uq    max neval
#>    f2 42.4 43.4 51.9473  44.00 44.6 2141.5  1000
#>    f3 63.1 65.6 68.9667  66.75 68.8  135.1  1000
```

Pros:

- fast and simple
- `dat` and `outliers` needn't be sorted
- ranges in `dat` can overlap

Cons:

- all data must be integer
- speed drops as the maximum value of `dat$X2` increases